# Django ignoring fixtures when run from tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, fixtures

I have a simple class in a Django app called "project"

`from django.test import TestCase`

```
class ProjectTest(TestCase):
"""Unit tests for the "Project" app """

fixtures = ['test_data.json', ]

def setUp(self):
    pass

def testTotalAmountOfWhuffie(self):
    """Tests that the calculation to find the total amount of Whuffie allocated is correct."""
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and when I run

`manage.py test project`

it completely ignores the fixtures. If I rename the file to initial_data.json it gets picked up by the test runner, so I'm sure the directory structure is right.

If I increase the verbosity of the test runs, they don't even look for the fixtures that I specify, I can even go as far as specifying the full path to the file, and they don't get loaded.

Comment: Can you list your directory structure?

Comment: The indentation of your example code is not correct, but i assume this just the formatting of your question (check here: http://djangotesting.com/en/latest/fixtures.html#fixtures-in-unit-tests). Where are your fixtures exactly located? Is FIXTURE_DIRS set in your settings.py? Can you load the fixtures using loaddata (http://readthedocs.org/docs/djtest/latest/ref/django-admin.html#django-admin-loaddata)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 'test_data.json' is under project/fixtures, then I can't see any problem with what you have got. Try using the fixture data in a test.

> > "it completely ignores the fixtures"

How do you know this?

> > "If I rename the file to initial_data.json it gets picked up by the test runner"

This is only picked up because the test runner runs syncdb. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures

> > "If I increase the verbosity of the test runs, they don't even look for the fixtures that I specify,"

How can you be sure? I ran my tests with the verbosity set to 3, and the test runner did not mention my fixtures at all. (The tests work)
I even tried using a non-existent fixture in the test. Again, the test runner did not mention any problem.

Comment: That single line of debug is really confusing.

The fixtures are loaded, despite the output suggesting they aren't.

Comment: I can see why. There's no obvious separation to the syncdb output, and the test output.